# django forms, replace label from model Form with instance, ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...

class Article(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='articles')
    ...

class Photography(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='photos')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos')
```

forms.py

```
from foo.models import Category, Article, Photography
from django import forms

class EditArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditArticleForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['category', 'second_field', 'another_one']
        widgets = {'category' : forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label=''),}
```

What I need is to replace category label with first photography which belongs to the article in the edit form. Form works as expected when I remove `widgets` line but I'm stuck trying to get empty label first but have this error `__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)` Thanks.

Comment: Please give the full traceback. Which `__init__` is being referred to?

Comment: thank you Daniel but I'm give up from this solution and find another one.